# FindRoot::dfmin: The minimal damping factor of 1/10000 has been reached

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, finite-element-method, boundary-conditions

I have to solve a highly nonlinear parametric system of three PDEs.
I don't know to which extent the results are trustable. Indeed, the graph shown
by ParametricNDSolve also presents the error message "FindRoot::dfmin: The minimal damping factor of 1/10000 has been reached". Here is the code.
Any help to fix this code is greatly welcome. Thanks.

```
(* fixed parameters *)
fixed = {Rext -> 1.5, DeltaP -> 1, pin -> 1, ps -> -0.62, Os -> 0.37, 
G2 -> 0.53, G3 -> 0.21, cs -> 0.5, phiiniz -> 0.4, c0 -> 0.07, 
c1 -> 2.49, c2 -> 1107, c3 -> 1.69, theta -> 310};

(*some auxiliary functions *)
f[xi_, alpha_] := 1/(1 + alpha* xi)
gamma[H_] := -1 + (1 - 
 H (c0 Exp[c1 H + c2 theta^(-1) Exp[-c3 H]]))^(-1)
CapGamma[x_] := x + G2 x^2 + G3 x^3
press[x_] := (pin - ps) - DeltaP *x

(*variable parameters *)
params = {alpha, G, A, T};

(* parametric system of pdes *)
eqns = {D[phi[x, t], x] == 
 16 G *f[xi[x, t], alpha] (DeltaP *Log[Rext])^(-1) ( 
   press[x] - 
    Os (CapGamma[c[x, t] (1 - phi[x, t])^(-1)] - CapGamma[cs]))*
  phi[x, t] (1 + gamma[phi[x, t]]), phi[0, t] == phiiniz, 
D[c[x, t], x] == 
 16 G * f[xi[x, t], phi[x, t]] (DeltaP *Log[Rext])^(-1) ( 
   press[x] - 
    Os (CapGamma[c[x, t] (1 - phi[x, t])^(-1)] - CapGamma[cs]))*
  c[x, t] (1 + gamma[phi[x, t]]), c[0, t] == 1, 
D[xi[x, t], t] == 
 G *f[xi[x, t], phi[x, t]] (DeltaP *Log[Rext])^(-1) ( 
    press[x] - 
     Os (CapGamma[c[x, t] (1 - phi[x, t])^(-1)] - CapGamma[cs]))*
   c[x, t] - 0.5*A*DeltaP*xi[x, t], xi[x, 0] == 0} /. fixed;

(*solving *)
 sol = ParametricNDSolve[eqns, {phi, c, xi}, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, T}, 
 params, MaxSteps -> Infinity];

(*visualization *)
 Manipulate[
 Plot3D[Evaluate[xi[alpha, G, A, T][x, t] /. sol], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, T},
 Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, t, xi}, AxesStyle -> Directive[16], 
Mesh -> False, PlotRange -> {Full, Full, All}], {alpha, 1, 10}, {G, 1,20}, {A, 1, 20}, {T, 1, 10}]
```

[image: solution]

> > FindRoot::dfmin: The minimal damping factor of 1/10000 has been reached.

Comment: Mathematica v12.2 creates several other messages like `ParametricNDSolve::fempsf: PDESolve could not find a solution.`

Comment: The first of these error messages in v12.3 is "NDSolve`FEM`InitializePDECoefficients::femcscd: The PDE is convection dominated and the result may not be stable. Adding artificial diffusion may help."  Look it up in the documentation and follow the recommendations.  Some experimentation may be required.

Comment: If `t` stands for time, then you should try to solve this as a time dependent problem. This means you'd need to give initial conditions for the time derivative and possibly add time derivatives for the other equations. If you click on the three ... of the error message it takes you to the documentation for this message that has an example: FEMDocumentation/ref/message/InitializePDECoefficients/femcscd. Also search this site for `femcscd`

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Try plotting the functions to see if there is a root, if not, you may be using a 'FindRoot' to do a 'FindMinimum' solution. If you just want to get rid of the error message, you could try ...,WorkingPrecision->55,MaxIterations->10000,Method->{"Newton", "StepControl" -> "TrustRegion"}]